# IPTABLES redirect specific wan traffic back to another address on wan

Tags: linux, iptables

What i am trying to achieve with iptables is setting a rule(s) that when a specific packet arrives from wan it gets redirected to a new address on wan.

Example:

Any UDP packet arriving on port 10000 gets redirected to 8.8.8.8:10000.
This can be more specific, like it originates from ip 1.1.1.1 or destination lan ip is 192.168.1.1 if there is a requirement for the rule to work.

Is this possible? Been trying a couple of rules in chain PREROUTING and using DNAT but i'm honestly in the dark here...

Answer (score 1):

**First**: your question is more appropriate at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

To answer your question: it isn't sufficient to only change the destination address because all returned datagrams would go directly from 8.8.8.8 to the original sender who could not relate them to the original datagrams.

So you would add DNAT rules in the PREROUTING chain and additional SNAT rules in the POSTROUTING chain so that the answers gets back to your machine and then can be sent back to the original sender with the appropriate addresses. You have to be very careful when designing these rules.

Comment: The question is off topic as you said. Do not answer off topic questions. Vote to close instead. [answer]